# Azure function returns HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have several Azure functions published and all but 2 of them work fine. The two that don't work are named "AdminData" and "AdminImage" and will be used to feed data to an administrative page. The code compiles fine, deploys fine, everything in the Azure dashboard looks fine but when I try calling them I always get the 404 Not Found error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that an Azure function name can't start with "Admin". I only found this out after hours of trial and error because no errors or warnings were thrown when the code was compiled or deployed. A subsequent search once I knew what the problem was turned up an issue report in github so it's a known problem;
 [Cannot have [FunctionName] starting with 'admin' #141](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/141)

This was a very frustrating problem that took a lot of time to figure out so hopefully, this post will help someone else avoid this trap.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much, I've spent hours trying to find out why my function wasnt working.. 3 years later after this post.